# Sending the form data using json formate

Tags: json, laravel

I am using the JSON format to send the form data using but there is found error that "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD". Actually I am using API of getting hotels.For this send the request through JSON format but I got error.

This is my API url in which I am sending the request- https://cdn.grnconnect.com/static-assets/documentation/GRN_v3-1.3/hotels/search_and_availability_request/#search-and-availability-request

```php
<form class="mt40 mb50" action="#" method="post" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="searchCity" id="searchCity">
    <input type="text" name="searchCityCode" id="searchCityCode">
    <input type="text" name="nationality" id="nationality">
    <input type="text" name="checkin" id="checkin">
    <input type="text" name="checkout" id="checkout">
    <select class="form-control" name="adult" id="adult" style="height:40px;">
        <option value="">Adult Member</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="awe-btn awe-btn-13 pr30 pl30 f16 bold font-hind"
            id="find">Find
    </button>
</form>
```

Script is-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#find").click(function(){
    var searchCity = $("#searchCity").val();
    var adults = $("#adults").val();
    var checkins = $("#checkin").val();
    var checkouts = $("#checkout").val();
    var nationality = $('#nationality').val();

    // Checking for blank fields.
    if (searchCity =='' || adults =='' || checkins =='' || checkouts =='' || nationality =='') {
      alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
    }
    else {
     $.ajax({
     url:'https://cdn.grnconnect.com/api/v3/hotels',
     type:'GET',
      Data: {destination_code: search City, check-in: check-ins, check out: checkouts,client_nationality: nationality, cutoff_time: 5000, more_results: true,
            hotel_info: false, rates: "comprehensive",rooms:adults},
    success:function(data){
         if(data['error'] == '0'){
             window.location.href = 'https://cdn.grnconnect.com/api/v3/hotels';
            }
        },
        error:function(e){
         alert("error in request");
        },
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you post your routes?

Comment: have you set your cors headers?

Comment: @prafulla there is no need of route because i am sending request on the url - https://cdn.grnconnect.com/api/v3/hotels using json formate by using above value

Comment: change `type:'POST',` to   `type:'GET',` and let me know, what error you are getting.

Comment: @prafulla i do this but got same error.

Comment: @Renu that is why I told you tell me the next error.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

Comment: @Renu have you changed the method type to `GET`?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu- yes

Comment: Can you put updated code to your question?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu-  yaa i  edit the above code.

Answer (score 0):

The route method is not specified in the route file for this route. Example:

```
Route::post('/hotels', 'HotelController@post')->name('hotel');
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL is incorrect, the URL should be:
https://cdn.grnconnect.com/api/v3/hotels/availability

Instead of https://cdn.grnconnect.com/api/v3/hotels/